# How do you specify environment specific inventory files?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a folder structure like so:

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── etc
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   ├── graphite.yml
│   │   │   ├── mongo.yml
│   │   │   ├── mysql.yml
│   │   │   └── rs4.yml
│   │   ├── inventory
│   │   └── products
│   │       ├── a.yml
│   │       ├── b.yml
│   │       └── c.yml
│   └── prod
│       ├── common
│       │   ├── graphite.yml
│       │   ├── mongo.yml
│       │   ├── redis.yml
│       │   └── rs4.yml
│       ├── inventory
│       └── products
│           ├── a.yml
│           ├── b.yml
│           └── c.yml
├── globals.yml
├── startup.yml
├── roles
|   └── [...]
└── requirements.txt
```

And in my `ansible.cfg`, I would like to do something like: `hostfile=./etc/{{ env }}/inventory`, but this doesn't work. Is there a way I can go about specifying environment specific inventory files in Ansible?

Comment: Environment based Ansible routines isn't really a good design. You routines should be the same across all your environments (with little changes if they do need to be there) so that you catch errors reliably. Rather the changes should be at the application/service level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume common and products are variable files.

As @Deepali Mittal already mentioned your inventory should look like `inventory/{{ env }}`.

In `inventory/prod` you would define a group `prod` and in `inventory/dev` you would define a group `dev`:

```
[prod]
host1
host2
hostN
```

This enables you to define group vars for `prod` and `dev`. For this simply create a folder `group_vars/prod` and place your vars files inside.

Re-ordered your structure would look like this:

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── dev
│   └── prod
├── group_vars
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   ├── graphite.yml
│   │   │   ├── mongo.yml
│   │   │   ├── mysql.yml
│   │   │   └── rs4.yml
│   │   └── products
│   │       ├── a.yml
│   │       ├── b.yml
│   │       └── c.yml
│   └── prod
│       ├── common
│       │   ├── graphite.yml
│       │   ├── mongo.yml
│       │   ├── mysql.yml
│       │   └── rs4.yml
│       └── products
│           ├── a.yml
│           ├── b.yml
│           └── c.yml
├── globals.yml
├── startup.yml
├── roles
|   └── [...]
└── requirements.txt
```

I'm not sure what `globals.yml` is. If it is a playbook, it is in the correct location. If it is a variable file with global definitions it should be saved as `group_vars/all.yml` and automatically would be loaded for all hosts.

Now you call ansible-playbook with the correct inventory file:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/prod startup.yml
```

I don't think it's possible to evaluate the environment inside the `ansible.cfg` like you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the tips -- quick question, if I have multiple folders in `prod` for my variables, will ansible auto-read these (i.e., the files in `common` and `product`)? Do you know at what depth it will go beyond `prod`?

Comment: Also, my goal for defining this in the `ansible.cfg` is so we could avoid having to specify the inventory file every time. We would run `startup.yml` and be prompted for which environment we want to work with, dynamically loading the inventory file for the environment chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `{{ env }}/inventory`, `/inventory/{{ env }}` should work. Also if you can please share how you use it right now and the error you get when you change the configuration to envs one